# Copying a variable in another file

Tags: swift, function, class, variables

I am trying to copy a variable in another file without success. Please note both classes are in different files.

In my first file I have this class:

```
class RelativeStrength: NSObject {

    func calculateRSI() {
        let relativeStrength1 = 87652
        let relativeStrength2 = 5634

        let rSI1 = 100 - (100 / (relativeStrength1 + 456))
        let rSI2 = 100 - (100 / (relativeStrength2 + 12))

        let average = (rSI1 + rSI2) / 2 

        print("average =", average)
    }
}
```

The function works perfectly when called from `viewWIllFinishLaunching` so I know `average` has a value and `calculateRSI()` is the first thing executed.

I'd like to access `average` here:

```
class OtherClass: RelativeStrength {

    var average2: Double = 0
    var three: Int = 0

    func setAverageCopy() {
        average2 = average
        print("average =", average)
        print("average2 =", average2)
    }

    func addition() {
        three = 1 + 2
        print("three =", three)
    }
}
```

The `addition()` function is here to check that my calls are executing, so when I call it from `viewDidLoad` I get `"three = 3"`. But when I call `setAverageCopy()` I get `"average = 0.0"` and `"average2 = 0.0"`.

What's wrong?

Comment: That shouldn't even compile.  In order to be able to access 'average' from the subclass 'OtherClass' you need to define it as a class instance variable just like you do 'average2'.

Comment: Your calculateRSI function doesn't output anything and/or the class RelativeStrength doesn't have a property to represent the average. Address those two issues and you should start to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you @UpholderOfTruth ! I solved it by declaring `var average: Double = RelativeStrength.average`